# composer require mongodb/mongodb failed

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu

In ubuntu 18.04, with php 5.6, php5.6-fpm, nginx, using ubuntu's mongodb

```
composer require mongodb/mongodb
```

Error

```
Using version ^1.4 for mongodb/mongodb
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.


Problem 1
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.4.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb has the wrong version (1.4.2) installed.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.4.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb has the wrong version (1.4.2) installed.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.4.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb has the wrong version (1.4.2) installed.
    - Installation request for mongodb/mongodb ^1.4 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2].
```

Comment: You need to update your pecl package for mongodb to at least ^1.5.0. http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.pecl.php

Comment: @luminoslty, I don't use pecl package to install them.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.php

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem I could solve it with:

```
composer require "mongodb/mongodb=^1.4.2" --ignore-platform-reqs
```